# cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.UI.Control>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, controlcollection

I would like to clear and dispose of all the components inside of an asp:panel. I am receiving the error:

cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Heres my code:

```
List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>(panelLayout.Controls);
panelLayout.Controls.Clear();
foreach (Control control in ctrls)
{
   control.Dispose();
}
```

Any ideas on what I need to change on line: List ctrls = new List(panelLayout.Controls);

Thanks, Larry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create a list first. You can iterate on your Controls collection.

```
foreach (Control control in panelLayout.Controls)
{
   control.Dispose();
}
panelLayout.Controls.Clear();
```

You get the error because `List<T>` expects a `IEnumerable<T>` in its constructor. Your collection doesn't implement that interface.

Also you have to clear the collection after you disposed them like jrummell pointed out.

Comment: You would probably need to clear the collection after looping through and Disposing.